# How to add Review from the iOS App in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I want to add the review from the iOS app. I have used the url and its redirecting to iTunes store, But my requirement is user can add review from the app.

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller

Comment: Import Storekit in your class and then call the function skreviewController.requestReview() whenever you want user to review.